# changing xml document lable (utf encoding) in php

Tags: php, xml

I have a strange problem. I am trying to load some xml document using DomDocumnet function but it throws a strange warning saying that :

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content

There is no other errors or warnings etc.
when I manually edit the xml file from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> to
```

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

it process it flawlessly .

I am looking for a solution by which i can just edit xml file in header before further processing.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the absolute  solution but a hack to solve this problem in such situations.

just replace the utf 16 to utf8 after loading the xml document as string and before further processing by using preg_replace function.

```
$source_xml_file = file_get_contents($incorrect_xml_file, TRUE);
$corrected_xml_file= preg_replace('/(<\?xml[^?]+?)utf-16/i', '$1utf-8', $source_xml_file);
$xmldoc->loadXML($corrected_xml_file);
```

works in my case.